# Getting an error when doing INSERT in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data-jpa, sql-insert

I get an

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "PRICEAFTERDISCOUNT" not found; SQL statement:
```

---

This is my Item class

```
package com.example.demo.model.persistence;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "item")
public class Item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonProperty
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @JsonProperty
    private String name;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @JsonProperty
    private BigDecimal price;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @JsonProperty
    private BigDecimal priceAfterDiscount;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @JsonProperty
    private String description;
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Item other = (Item) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

And this is my `data.sql` file

```
insert into item (name, price, priceAfterDiscount, description) values ('Travel Card Holder', 9.25, 0, 'A holder for your travel card');

insert into item (name, price, priceAfterDiscount, description) values ('Personalised cufflinks', 45.00, 0, 'Cufflings with your initials');

insert into item (name, price, priceAfterDiscount, description) values ('Kids T-shirt', 19.95, 0, 'A T-shirt with dinosaurs')
```

As far as I can tell, I have added the `priceAfterDiscount` into my insert statement so I do not
understand where the error comes from, or why it occurs in the first place. Please help!
I have added the priceAfterDiscount field in the Item class. And annotated the same way as the rest of the fields. Also, the syntax looks correct to me

Answer (score 2):

The exception means your database table `item` does not contain a column named `PRICEAFTERDISCOUNT`. Check database column name and add it over field annotation argument this way `@Column(name="database_column_name", nullable = false)`.

`data.sql` statements have to contain the right column names also.